# Slim Exception: Identifier "myNonWorkingVariable" is not defined

Tags: php, exception, slim

Hello I'm using slim framework in PHP and I'm getting the following exception:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: Slim\Exception\ContainerValueNotFoundException
Message: Identifier "myNonWorkingVariable" is not defined.
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error because all other variables which perform similar task and are used similarly like this variable are working fine without any error.

Below is my class:

```
<?php


namespace Project\CF;


use Project\CM\Package\MySomeClass;

class MyClass
{

    protected $parts;
    protected $somePDO;
    protected $myNonWorkingVariable;
    protected $workingVariable;

    private function __construct(PartsAndPDO $pnp, $type, $value)
    {
        $this->parts = $pnp->getParts();
        $this->somePDO = $pnp->getSomePDO();
        $this->myNonWorkingVariable = $type;
        $this->workingVariable = $value;
    }

    function get()
    {
        return function ($request, $response, $next) {

            $type = $this->myNonWorkingVariable;
            /**
             * The above line throws the following exception, no matter what variable I use here:
             * Slim Application Error
            The application could not run because of the following error:

            Details

            Type: Slim\Exception\ContainerValueNotFoundException
            Message: Identifier "myNonWorkingVariable" is not defined.
             */

            /* The below variables $this->parts, $this->workingVariable works fine in below codebase*/
            if (!in_array("some value", $this->parts))
                $someClass = new MySomeClass($type);
                $workWithThis = $someClass->get($this->somePDO, $request, $this->workingVariable);

                $request = $request->withAttribute('key', $workWithThis);
            }

            $response = $next($request, $response);

            return $response;
        };
    }
}
```

I have provided comments where I have mentioned that other variables `$this->parts, $this->workingVariable` works fine in codebase. They are also initialized in the exact same way as `myNonWorkingVariable`. Still it is `myNonWorkingVariable` which is causing problem, no matter where I use it in whichever line inside the function.

I also tried the following change in codebase:

```
$type = $this->workingVariable;
```

Then the exception changes to:

```
Message: Identifier "workingVariable" is not defined.
```

Spent few hours till now still I have no clue why this is happening.

**Any idea why is this happening?**

Answer (score 0):

The get function contained an anonymous function, which had params that would never get passed to it.

```
<?php
namespace Project\CF;

use Project\CM\Package\MySomeClass;

class MyClass
{

    protected $parts;
    protected $somePDO;
    protected $myNonWorkingVariable;
    protected $workingVariable;

    private function __construct(PartsAndPDO $pnp, $type, $value)
    {
        $this->parts = $pnp->getParts();
        $this->somePDO = $pnp->getSomePDO();
        $this->myNonWorkingVariable = $type;
        $this->workingVariable = $value;
    }

    function get($request, $response, $next) {
    {
        $type = $this->myNonWorkingVariable;

        if (!in_array("some value", $this->parts))
            $someClass = new MySomeClass($type);
            $workWithThis = $someClass->get($this->somePDO, $request, $this->workingVariable);

            $request = $request->withAttribute('key', $workWithThis);
        }

        $response = $next($request, $response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```